# My first course in algebraic geometry: two simple questions

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

I'm attending my first course in algebraic geometry, and my professor has chosen an approach which is a middle-way between the basic algebraic geometry done in $\mathbb A^n_k$ and the approach with schemes, so substantially like in [Milne's notes](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/AG.pdf). I have for you some simple question and I hope that the answers will not involve scheme theory:

1) Let $(X,\mathcal O_X)$ an affine variety, so it is isomorphic as ringed space to $(V,\mathcal O_V)$ where $V$ is an affine algebraic set and $\mathcal O_V$ is the sheaf of regular functions. When one says "take the covering of $X$ with standard open sets", it means that we consider the covering of $X$ done with those open sets of $X$  which are homeomorphic to the standard open sets $D(f)\subseteq V$?

2) In class we have defined a quasi-coherent sheaf on $(V,\mathcal O_V)$ (we are in $\mathbb A^n_k$) as the sheaf $\widetilde M $ uniquely associated to the assignment $\widetilde M(D(f))=M_f$ where $M$ is a $\Gamma(V,\mathcal O_V)$-module. When we talk about a quasi-coherent sheaf defined on a abstract affine variety $(X,\mathcal O_X)$ so isomorphic to  $(V,\mathcal O_V)$, do we intend a sheaf $\mathcal F$ on $X$ with an isomorphism $\mathcal F\cong f_{\ast}\widetilde M$ (assuming that $f$ is the omeomorphism between $V$ and $X$)?

Comment: (1) No. It is not just homeomorphic but _identified with_ the corresponding standard open set in $V$ by a fixed isomorphism $X \cong V$. (2) Yes. You can check that this notion is independent of the choice of $V$ and of the choice of isomorphism $X \cong V$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1) Standard open sets are defined for every locally ringed space. If $f \in \Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$, then $X_f$ (sometimes also called $D(f)$) is by definition the set of all $x \in X$ such that $f_x \notin \mathfrak{m}_x$, where $\mathfrak{m}_x$ is the maximal ideal of the local ring $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$. Equivalently, $f(x) \neq 0$ in the residue field $k(x) = \mathcal{O}_{X,x}/\mathfrak{m}_x$. This is also the reason why often $X_f$ is called the "locus where $f$ doesn't vanish" or "where $f$ is invertible". It is an easy exercise to show that $X_f$ is in fact open, and that we have the standard identities $X_1 = X$, $X_f \cap X_g = X_{fg}$. When $X$ is an affine algebraic set, this coincides with the locus where $f$ doesn't vanish defined in the usual sense (and probably this is what you meant by $D(f) \subseteq V$).

2) Again quasi-coherent sheaves make sense for arbitrary ringed spaces. And it is a very bad idea to give definitions only for algebraic sets $\subseteq \mathbb{A}^n$ and try to extend them via chosen isomorphisms! You should work with *intrinsic geometric objects* instead, and (locally) ringed spaces provide a nice framework for that. So let's use this language.

A quasi-coherent module on a ringed space $X$ is just a module $M$ (i.e. what most people call a sheaf of modules) on $X$ such that locally on $X$ there is a presentation $\mathcal{O}^{\oplus I} \to \mathcal{O}^{\oplus J} \to M \to 0$. So to be more precise: There is an open covering $X = \cup_i X_i$ such that for each $i$ there is an exact sequence (which, of course, does not belong to the data) $\mathcal{O}|_{X_i}^{\oplus I} \to \mathcal{O}|_{X_i}^{\oplus J} \to M|_{X_i} \to 0$. Quasi-coherent modules constitute a (tensor) category $\mathrm{Qcoh}(X)$, which is by the way a very interesting and deep invariant of $X$, especially when $X$ is a variety.

How to construct quasi-coherent modules on a ringed space $X$? Well pick a $\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$-module $M$. Then I claim that we can construct a quasi-coherent module $\tilde{M}$ on $X$ as follows: Choose a presentation $\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)^{\oplus I} \to \Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)^{\oplus J} \to M \to 0.$ Represent the morphism on the left as a "relation matrix" consisting of elements of $\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$. Now, every such global section corresponds to a homomorphism $\mathcal{O}_X \to \mathcal{O}_X$. Thus we can produce a matrix consisting of endomorphisms over $\mathcal{O}_X$, and thus a morphism $\mathcal{O}_X^{\oplus I} \to \mathcal{O}_X^{\oplus J}$. Define $\tilde{M}$ to be the cokernel. By definition, this is quasi-coherent! This already produces lots of examples; in fact all $X$ is an affine variety, but only few if $X$ is projective.

To give a more concise definition which does not depend on the presentation: Just define $\tilde{M}$ to be the sheaf associated to the presheaf $U \mapsto \Gamma(U,\mathcal{O}_X) \otimes_{\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)} M$. This definition easily implies a more conceptual characterization of the functor $M \to \tilde{M}$ from $\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$-modules to quasi-coherent modules modules on $X$: It is left adjoint to the global section functor! In fact, everything you want to know about $\tilde{M}$ already follows from this adjunction. You may forget about the details of the construction, you just have to remember $\hom(\tilde{M},F) \cong \hom(M,\Gamma(X,F))$, which actually holds for every module $F$ on $X$.

So what happens when $X$ is some affine variety? Then the sets $X_f$ constitute a basis for the topology of $X$, and we have $\Gamma(X_f,\mathcal{O}_X) = \Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)_f$. Namely, this is well-known if $X \subseteq \mathbb{A}^n$ and then generalizes immediately to affine varieties, which are isomorphic as ringed spaces to such concrete varieties. Let $M$ be a $\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$-module. Now it turns out that the presheaf defined above is actually a sheaf! This comes down to the following: If $f_1,\dotsc,f_n \in \Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ generate the unit ideal (i.e. the corresponding sets $X_{f_i}$ cover $X$), then the canonical sequence

$$0 \to M \to \prod_{i} M_{f_i} \to \prod_{i,j} M_{f_i f_j}$$

is exact. Everyone should have done this proof instead of looking it up in the standard sources. Because I think it is quite enlightening and in fact purely geometric if you think of $f_1,\dotsc,f_n$ as a partition of unity.

Anyway, so this tells us that we don't need associated sheaves in the definition of $\tilde{M}$. Thus, by definition, on the open subset $X_f$ it is given by

$$\Gamma(X_f,\tilde{M}) = \Gamma(X_f,\mathcal{O}_X) \otimes_{\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)} M = \Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)_f \otimes_{\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)} M = M_f.$$

So this describes some quasi-coherent sheaves on affine varieties. In fact, one can show that *every* quasi-coherent sheaf on an affine variety $X$ has the form $\tilde{M}$. Namely, one shows that for every such sheaf $F$ the canonical counit morphism of the adjunction mentioned above $\tilde{\Gamma(X,F)} \to F$ is an isomorphism. Again, this is a very nice exercise. After some thought you will see that this is just another application of the exact sequence above. So this provides, for every *affine* variety, an equivalence of categories

$$\mathrm{Qcoh}(X) \cong \mathrm{Mod}(\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)).$$

By the way, if you *define* $\tilde{M}$ on an affine variety by $\Gamma(X_f,\tilde{M}) = M_f$ and extended via projective limits to arbitrary open subsets, then you probably would like to know that this is a sheaf. And again this comes down to the exact sequence above. You cannot get around it. I don't like this approach because it is somewhat clumsy, you don't get the general picture, and it doesn't produce a formula for $\tilde{M}(U)$ for arbitrary $U$. Therefore I've chosen the rather abstract but hopefully concise approach above. Of course nothing is new, you can find all that in EGA I, the Stacks Project, etc.

Comment: can you give me a hint to prove that $X_f$ is open in $X$?

Comment: Hint: $x \in X_f$ iff $f_x$ has an inverse in the stalk $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$.